# React Native app crashes on initial install when first opened

Tags: android, react-native

I have a react native app that crashes the first time after it is downloaded from the play store.

After it crashes, you can open it again, and it works fine.

It is only affected the first time it opens.

This is the log from when it crashes the first time:

```
[09:48:54] D | ReactNative ▶︎ [CodePush] Loading JS bundle from "assets://index.android.bundle"

[09:48:54] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.ctor()

[09:48:54] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
                           └ ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
```

After that, it crashes.